# Figuring out lost configurations for ubuntu EC2 server

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to figure out which of the packages from the below list works with Nginx server. Actually past coder hasn't made any docs to follow and is unreachable. When customer restarted EC2 server now it is showing Bad Gateway on Nginx. I've started Nginx and its working fine but couldn't figure out which tool is serving data to socket/http. Following is the list of all installed packages on Ubuntu.

```
 kmod
  landscape-client
  networking
  nginx
  openbsd-inetd
  pppd-dns
  procps
  pure-ftpd
  resolvconf
  sendsigs
  udev
  unattended-upgrades
  urandom
  x11-common
```

In "etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite" it shows following reverse proxy.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on ssl;
    ssl_certificate     mysite.com_2.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key mysite.com.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'Not Shown Purposely :ECDH$
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    server_tokens off;
    location / {
        root /home/mysite/www/website;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @python;
    }

    location ^~ /assets {
        root /home/mysite/Project;
```

[image]

Found the upstart script:

```
# upstart-socket-bridge - Bridge socket events into upstart
#
# This helper daemon receives socket(7) events and
# emits equivalent Upstart events.

description     "Bridge socket events into upstart"

emits socket

start on net-device-up IFACE=lo
stop on runlevel [!2345]

expect daemon
respawn

exec upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
```

Comment: check the nginx conf located in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ that to which port reverse proxy is set

Comment: I've added info in main question.

Comment: include full config, i could not see any `proxy` configuration

Comment: On netstats it shows information attached to question as image.

Comment: check /var/log/upstart/ for service logs & /etc/init/ directory for application service config

Comment: Found the upstart script but its configured as daemon. How to restart it? Shouldn't it work with the restart as per code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140212/discussion-between-sideffect0-and-shazia-nusrat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most command web application setups nginx configured such that it acts as a reverse proxy for a program or http/tcp service.

- Bad Gateway means some reverse proxy setup is running is stopped, run `sudo nginx -t` for getting any nginx conf errors if any.
- Check the nginx configuration included in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` folder for conf files.
- You will be able to find instructions like `proxy http://localhost:8080`.
- using `lsof` or `netstat` find which program is running on that port.
- Check the program's log file for solving the issue.

NOTE:  If it is a system service file managed by `upstart` you can find the log in `/var/log/upstart/` directory & conf in `/etc/init/`.
run `lsof -i :port -S` to findout which program is running on that port`

Comment: Nginx shows working fine. All I need is to get the tool old coder used and I can do the rest. Thank you for helping me to narrow it down till now.